# relatorio filtro excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

estou tentando fazer um relatório mas preciso de uma ajuda a planilha tem que pesquisar por data e colar em outra planilha os dados dessa mesma data (exemplo na linha que tem data de hoje copiar tudo de hoje e colar na outra planilha).
        link da planilha https://drive.google.com/open?id=17lExk1BkDxXVctEXj7hxjl2clMOAx2u4

Comment: Por favor, insira seus códigos já tentados ou mais informações para que possamos ajudar. Veja [como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ok topico corrigido

Answer (score 1):

No UserForm1 use o código abaixo:

```
Dim wsR As Worksheet
Dim wsD As Worksheet
Dim ul  As Long

If cdDataINI <> "" Or cdDataFIM <> "" Then
    Set wsR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RELATORIO")
    ul = wsR.Cells(wsR.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    If wsR.Range("XFC1").Value = "" Then
        wsR.Range("F1").Copy wsR.Range("XFC1:XFD1")
    End If

    wsR.Range("A1:G" & ul + 1).ClearContents
    wsR.Range("XFC2").Value = ">=" & Format(cdDataINI, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    wsR.Range("XFD2").Value = "<=" & Format(cdDataFIM, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    Set wsD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("dados")
    ul = wsD.Cells(wsD.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    wsD.Range("A1:G" & ul).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, wsR.Range("XFC1:XFD2"), wsR.Range("A1"), False

    MsgBox "Processo concluído - " & cdDataINI & " à " & cdDataFIM
End If
```